# Enable smooth scrolling in fresh ubuntu 15.04

Tags: touchpad, 15.04, scrolling

So, I've just reinstalled ubuntu on my Dell Latitude E7440 after messing up the previous install completely. Everything seems to work fine, except my much beloved smooth scrolling. Normally, I'd think that smooth scrolling just wasn't supported for my trackpad, but I've had smooth scrolling on this very laptop before. I'm wondering if I need to install additional drivers, perhaps some of you can give me a hint?

Best regards

Comment: Seems I have the same issue on Dell Latitude E6410